# Optimal way to transfer account's balance between people

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I am looking for an optimal way to transfer funds between accounts to make sure that everyone has the same amount on their account. I've calculated correctly number that should be a result in every account but I am searching for an algorithm for who to who should transfer and how much funds (without central bank) so everyone results with the same balance.

### Example

```
+--------+---------+
| person | balance |
+--------+---------+
| A      | 7 500   |
| B      | -2 500  |
| C      | -10 000 |
| D      | 15 000  |
+--------+---------+
```

In this example everyone should end up with balance o 2 500. To achieve that:

- Person A should transfer 5 000 to person B
- Person D should transfer 12 500 to person C

To sum it up data I have is:

- number of people (>= 2)
- starting balance of every person
- what balance should every person have after transfers

Is there any algorithm for that? Is that an NP-complete problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP-hard. It's essentially equivalent to [this other problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414875/how-to-calculate-minimum-amount-of-transactions-needed-for-n-friends-to-clear-th):

> Given a group of people and an amount of credits and debits, find the minimum number of transfers between those people to settle all credits and debits.

Here, your goal is to make everyone's total equal to the average, which basically is the same problem as the one above once you subtract the average total from everyone's account.